# Installing Azure pyodbc Driver on Heroku

Tags: python, azure, heroku, pyodbc

My app is deployed on Heroku right now, but when I connect my Azure database using the pyodbc module, I get the error:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib > 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Traceback:

```
server = servername
database = dbname
username = un
password = pw
driver= 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'

connStr = 'DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password
db = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
cursor = db.cursor()
```

I can run the above code and query the database on localhost, but I imagine something isn't configured correctly on Heroku's side.

Note: I also have the Heroku apt buildpack installed: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt

My Aptfile has this:

```
unixodbc
unixodbc-dev
python-pyodbc
libsqliteodbc
unixodbc-dev-utf16
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your code, seems like there is a missing `'` in the line `connStr = DRIVER=`

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wrong: it's looking for a driver called `'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'`, but: `file not found` it can't find a file with that name. I'd suggest you Google the error, and also consult the documentation for the type of database you're trying to connect to. Also to point out, the Port# is mentioned twice. (Details matter!)  Another good resource for connection strings: **https://www.connectionstrings.com/**